# MPAndroidChart - How to set range values from BarChart at 2.0.9v?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I´m using MPAndroidChart 2.0.9 version. I would like to set labels on y-axis from 0 to 100 and display always this range, but i can´t find the chart.setYRange() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The range can be customized via the `YAxis` class.

Here is the documentation: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/YAxis-%28YLabels%29

```
YAxis y = chart.getAxisLeft();
y.setAxisMaxValue(100);
y.setAxisMinValue(0);
```

Comment: this will not work if the AxisMinValue value is different from zero. for AxisMinValue value different from zero you will need to use `yl.setStartAtZero(false);` before setting the new starting value (different from zero) by using `yl.setAxisMinValue(...);`

Answer (score 2):

You can try to write this:

```
yAxis.setLabelCount(x)
```

This code should give you labels in steps of x, assuming you set a min and max value.

Example of my code:

```
YAxis y = mChart.getAxisLeft();
        y.setAxisMaxValue(100);
        y.setAxisMinValue(0);
        y.setLabelCount(6);
```

This will give me labels from 0 to 100 in 6 steps, so: 0-20-40-60-80-100.